# Incorrect database diagram - MySQL Workbench options

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a database diagram designed in MySQL Workbench, and I have my database fully exported in a file (.sql), I also have later versions (incremental backup).

In summary, I have the following files:

```
database.mwb
database.sql
updateA.sql
updateB.sql
updateC.sql
updateD.sql
updateE.sql
updateF.sql
```

The problem is, that the diagram "database.mwb" does not match any of the databases, (Surely someone else has modified it and never exported the changes).

I have tested the difference...

- ... between "database.mwb" and "database.sql"
- ... between "database.mwb" and a file that I created with the contents of all the updated ones (copied and pasted manually by me)
- ... between "database.mwb" and export phpMyAdmin (database.sql + updateA + updateB)

In conclusion, I want to have my updated "database.mwb" diagram and I do not know what to do. Maybe reverse engineer to generate the new diagram, but there are more than 500 tables to organize again.

Is there any way to tell MySQL Workbench to modify the diagram based on the SQL file?

Answer (score 0):

What should work is:

1. Create your schema from the original model file in the target server.
2. Apply the next update script on the server.
3. Synchronize your model with the server, taking over all changes from there.
4. Fix the model (layout etc.).
5. repeat steps 2 - 4 for each update script.

Comment: I have noticed that the greatest amount of changes is the index problem. So that in some version of MySQL they automatically changed the indexes from "fx_indexname" to "fx_indexname_idx". I do not know what I should configure to tell Workbench not to consider those changes.